# Проблема с установкой Kivi на Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, kivy

Проблемы с установкой `Kivi` с консоли.
Прописываю `python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1`
Выдается ошибка:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1
Collecting kivy==1.11.1
  Using cached Kivy-1.11.1.tar.gz (23.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4 in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from kivy==1.11.1) (0.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from kivy==1.11.1) (0.16)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from kivy==1.11.1) (2.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (2.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (1.25.9)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (2020.4.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\megaa\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy==1.11.1) (3.0.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: kivy
  Building wheel for kivy (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477:
   command: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\megaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-57g12q0m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\megaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-57g12q0m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-xeoguf6o'
       cwd: C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-57g12q0m\kivy\
  Complete output (531 lines):
  Using setuptools
  User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
  Using this graphics system: OpenGL
  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

  WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

  b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

  
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy
  Running setup.py clean for kivy
Failed to build kivy
Installing collected packages: kivy
    Running setup.py install for kivy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477:
     command: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\megaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-57g12q0m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\megaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-57g12q0m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0l_k634_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Program Files\Python38\Include\kivy'
         cwd: C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-57g12q0m\kivy\
    Complete output (513 lines):
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\kivy

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 3221225477: 'C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\megaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-57g12q0m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\megaa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-57g12q0m\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\megaa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0l_k634_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Program Files\Python38\Include\kivy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, проблема заключается в установленной на данный момент **версии** Python. Если у тебя версия **3.8.x** и более, то попробуй сменить её на более старую, примерно **3.7.x**. Если есть проблемы со сменой версии, вот руководство по его смене:

Узнаём расположение нашего Python (в пуске ищем папку Python, кликаем ПКМ по ней, нажимаем на пункт "Расположение файла", дальше, если видим ярлыки вместо папок и файлов питона, нажимаем ПКМ по ярлыку, и жмём "Расположение файла", так мы оказались в директории питона), переходим в папку Scripts, копируем путь к ней. Далее с помощью поиска, пишем ключевые слова: переменных сред, нажимаем на Изменение системных переменных среды. Нажимаем на кнопку "Переменные среды...". Выбираем переменную "PATH" и нажимаем "Изменить". Нажимаем на кнопку "Создать" и вставляем путь к папке Scripts, скопированный нами ранее. Сохраняем это всё, выходим из окон. Перезапускаем cmd, вуаля!

Источник: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NTIn3-Oylc

Comment: Последняя поддерживаемая версия python для kivy - 3.7?

Comment: Нет, только на данный момент поддерживаемая. Вскоре будут доступны и другие версии.

Comment: ну, поскольку я только учусь, может обойдусь пока tkinter или pyqt...

Comment: Да, в Kivy используется ООП, поэтому если Вы его не изучали, не стоит пока браться за это. Попробуйте те модули о которых вы сказали.

Comment: с ООП нет проблем, знаю с с++, с#, js и давно выучил в python. Нет определенной темы для обучения, поэтому пока учу все подряд...

Comment: Раз Вы так продвинулись в этой области, то попробуйте поискать в Youtube ролик на эту тематику, там их не так много, но полезного для начального уровня могут дать. Если Вы умеете читать документацию на английском - есть официальная версия от создателей, где всё описано - https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/kivy/latest/kivy.pdf

Comment: прочитать это можно, но нет смысла откатывать версию только ради kivy если мне надо только для обучения без цели

Comment: Действуйте как считаете нужным, можете сменять версии после того как использовали Kivy. Туда и обратно под нужды.